# create table dynamically using ngfor. ERROR Error: Provided data source did not match an array, Observable, or DataSource

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi i have a component where in the html have a code like

```
<div *ngFor="let group of groups; index as index">
  <div *ngIf="group0.lenght > 0">
     <mat-table [datasource]="'group'+index">

     </mat-table>
  </div>
</div>
```

before i have a code that filter the items by the groupid like a foreign key

```
group0 = this.items.filter(x => x.group_uuid == this.groups[i].uuid)
groupn = this.items.filter(x => x.group_uuid == this.groups[n].uuid)
```

but the problem is when the table appears, i got the next error:
ERROR Error: Provided data source did not match an array, Observable, or DataSource

any idea? thanks in advance

Comment: what is the type for this.items? an array of what?

Comment: You need to put all your groups in an array. Right now you pass a string to `datasource` instead of an array. It's the same as trying to call a variable by string with name of the variable. As long the `c = a + b` not equal to `c = 'a' + 'b'` code above will not be working.

Comment: What is `group0` in line 2?

Comment: what is your definition of "groups"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need store groups in an array.

```
groupsOfItems = this.groups
  .map(group => this.items.filter(x => x.group_uuid === group.uuid));
```

in template:

```
<div *ngFor="let group of groupsOfItems; index as index">
  <div *ngIf="group.lenght > 0">
     <mat-table [datasource]="group">

     </mat-table>
  </div>
</div>
```